# xcode - git permission issue

Tags: xcode, git, permissions, git-push

After long time working on a shared xcode project, a permission issue is appearing during push phase.
Xcode shows the message :" The operation could not be performed because do not have permission to modify MyBranch ".
This is quite annoying and force to change permission "by hand" of same files. 
Anyone know what is the reason/solution of that?
Tx in advance.